# Add Text before product price should only affect certain products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets

In Wordpress I use a custom code "unit_price" for certain products in the My Fields area. This will display a special price in the category and product view with a text before and after the price. Unfortunately, the second part of this code affects all products. I would like it so the code area with the "like price" only affects the products where I have entered a "unit_price". If that is not possible, it would also be conceivable z.b. show the text in front of the price if the Unit_Price is greater than 50,00 €. Would be super nice if someone could help me. Thank you.

The whole thing I have built as a snippet in Wordpress.

```
function sv_change_product_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    $unit_price = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'unit_price', true );
    if ( ! empty( $unit_price ) ) {
        $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( $unit_price ) . ' / Stück</span>';    
    }

    return $price_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sv_change_product_html', 10, 2 );




add_filter("wc_price","addtext",10,4);
function addtext($return, $price, $args, $unformatted_price){
    if(is_product_category() || is_shop() || is_product()){
        $return =  'like Preis:'.$return;
    }
    return $return;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the string to $price_html and return.

```
function sv_change_product_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    $unit_price = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'unit_price', true );
    if ( ! empty( $unit_price ) ) {
        $price_html = 'like Preis:'.$price_html;
    }

    return $price_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'sv_change_product_html', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you. But now the supplement would be removed after price (/ Stück).         $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( $unit_price ) . ' / Stück</span>';